# How can i create xlsx in pyspark? i dont need csv

Tags: pyspark

I want to get xslx insted of csv in pyspark

i tried changing "CSV" FOR "XLSX"
[this is the part of the code where the csv ar created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3rkR.png)

this is writing in dataiku and i need to create xlsx insted of csv.
thnaks

Comment: You could just use csv and then use the openpyxl library to convert csv to excel

Comment: there's a package that lets you export to excel files - [see](https://saturncloud.io/blog/writing-spark-dataframe-directly-to-excel-with-databricks/)